# does subtracting means affect a least squares solution?

Tags: least-squares

Suppose I have the usual overdetermined $A x = b$ system. The least squares solution is then $x = (A'A)^{-1}A'b$.

Suppose I want to subtract the mean of each row of $A$ from $A$ and the corresponding row of $b$. Let $k$ be this column vector of row means and $K$ be $k$ replicated horizontally to match the number of columns in $A$. Then the new system is $(A-K)x' = (b-k)$. Is the least squares solution $x' = x$ ?

Well, expanding the new system out we get $Ax' - Kx' = b - k.$ Assuming $x' = x$ indeed, then we're saying that $Kx = k$, which is true only if $sum(x) = 1$. That seems like an unlikely result of the least squares solution, so I'm guessing the answer to the titled question is "yes."

However, just because $x' \neq x$ doesn't say anything about the residual.

I'm having trouble reasoning about this.

The actual application involved is machine learning, where I would without thinking go and subtract the mean of an image patch before processing, and add that mean back in at the end. I am attempting to justify doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose I want to subtract the mean of each row of $A$ from $A$ and the corresponding row of $b$.

You can see that this can affect the solution even by looking only at $A$. Suppose $$A = I_{2, 2},$$

that is, the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix. Then, if you subtract the mean of each row, you get

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0.5 & -0.5\\
-0.5 & 0.5
\end{bmatrix},
$$

which is nonsingular (the rows sum to $0$).

As another counterexample (in Python):

```
In [24]: from scipy import linalg

In [25]: import numpy as np

In [26]: A = np.array([[1, 3], [6, 1]])

In [29]: b = np.array([1, 1])

In [30]: linalg.solve(A, b)
Out[30]: array([ 0.11764706,  0.29411765])

In [31]: linalg.solve(A - np.mean(A, axis=1), b - np.mean(A, axis=1))
Out[31]: array([ 0.27777778,  1.44444444])
```

Comment: The python counterexample left out b's definition, and A - np.mean(A, axis=1) doesn't work for me in Python 3.5.2. No worries, I was able to make the code work, and the result makes it very clear I should not be subtracting means.

Comment: @WaltDonovan You're right about `b` - added it. The code works for me on Python 3.5.2, so that's a bit curious, but that's maybe more for StackOverflow than CrossValidated.

Comment: Ahh. Your code works only if A is a square matrix -- my test case had A as a 4 x 2 matrix.